# Metamorphosis Lycanthropy

Tags: biology, creature-design, science-fiction, mythical-creatures

Edit 1.5

You are a biologist and have perfected a Werewolf Serum 6, a special virus that interacts with the brain and will make a human turn into a werewolf-like animal. The serum is created with wolf DNA, human DNA, and some other factors. People infected can transmit the serum through their bodily fluids like saliva. The virus can only go through liquids, not the air. It only affects humans but the virus can be carried by other animals. You have roughly a million dollars and twenty gallons of the serum.  You need half a teaspoon for it to effect a person. It is easily mass-produced and your goal is to spread it to as many people as possible and turn humanity into beasts. If successful you plan on living your life happily in an underground bunker with some friends.

Week 1 of getting the serum: nothing.

Week 2-9: the person starts eating more meat-based diet and eating much more.Increased sex drive and can contaminate through bodily fluids. Excess hair and clawed hands starts growing.

Week 10: the person runs away into the woods and survives there. The person forms a caterpillar-like chrysalis and eats lots of food before going inside.

Week 11: the person comes out as a wolf-like humanoid. They have a tail, heightened senses, a short snout, sharp teeth, fur, claws with a thumb, increased strength, endurance and wolf-like instincts. They have decreased intelligence.

Afterwards they will live in the forest and search for a mate or another werewolf to form a pack and to have babies. If they cannot find one they will find a human of the opposite gender to infect and kidnap. They would then protect them as they shift. You have easy access to many different countries. The following statistics should help you know how to spread the serum.

Using these statistics, what would the best way to infect as many people as possible?
Edit: check out Metamorphosis Lycanathropy (ML) part 2 ([Metamorphosis Lycanthropy Part 2](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/126470/metamorphosis-lycanthropy-part-2))

Comment: If you're interested in realism, I suspect your timeframe will need to be longer. "Week 5" and "Week 6" will probably become closer to "Week 15" (it takes time to build the reserves for hibernation, metamorphosis, etc.) and "Week 30" (since metamorphosis is a time-consuming process, especially since you're trying to grow new limbs, modify bone structure in the face, and more). You can handwave it away or ignore that bit if you like, for the sake of your story, but it's worth keeping that in mind.

Comment: I forsee a big problem. Metamorphosis requires extreme amounts of fat (and as Palarran mentioned time). So your pre-werewolves would need to eat to morbid obesity... In the forest. So as they get closer to transforming they have a harder time catching their prey. Actually imagine that: a bunch of morbidly obese people waggling through the forest hoping to catch something.

Comment: @Demigan I don't think "morbid obesity" would be necessary. Bears manage to set enough by to hibernate through winter; they grow noticeably in weight, but not to the point of becoming obese. Although I have to admit, that scene you're imagining _would_ be quite hilarious.

Comment: I am worried.  I am already at stage 4, except with no woods and double the excess hair.  But stage 5 might be ok; especially the gong part.

Comment: @Demigan Perhaps instead of actually switching to a meat-based diet in stage 2, they just start hoarding meat. Vast amounts of it, for no readily apparent purpose. Then, when they have it all stashed in their den, they begin the transformation by gorging themselves.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I agree the weeks might need to adjusted and more time to build up body fat/energy.

Comment: @Cadence That one might have problems with food preservation. By the time enough meat was hoarded, some of it would probably be going rotten (unless it's frozen, which is going to cause problems when gorging time comes and instinct is likely overriding all reason). Also, there's a practical limit to how much the body can digest at a time. Frankly, I'd suggest that weeks 2 and 3 substitute a greatly increased craving for food (not specifically meat yet, that can wait for the final stage), so that by the time week 4 rolls around your victims are already close to having the reserves to transform.

Comment: "*Week 2: the person starts eating more meat-based diet.*" I knew there was something odd about Jordan B Peterson!!!

Comment: Why is there a chrysalis involved?

Comment: Your question is being flagged as too broad & opinion based. Please edit down to a single focused topic. Also, you might consider editing out the fluff in the middle. How the serum is produced and the stages of dehumanisation are really not relevant to the actual question which amounts to "how do I deliver this serum to the maximum number of people".

Comment: The chrysalis is to protect the human as it changes. while inside a special liquid will fill it up. It'll semi-dissolve the skeletal structure and reshape it. The fat is to supply for this and the added muscle.

Comment: @elemtilas The stages do have some relevance: contagious victims without significant symptoms are a great way to further spread a virus, so it's important to know what timeframe is present. Serum production is also highly relevant, as it indicates what means are plausible: budgets of $100 versus $100 billion would produce rather different results. "The best way to maximize the spread of disease X" is _very much dependent_ on the details you're dismissing as "fluff".

Comment: Can you guys "unhold" it now? i agree with Palarran's statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with Palarran your time frame is way off on how long the transformation will take, also since both are mammals it is possible for the transformation to take place without the chrysalis, that way the creature can keep feeding itself and stay away fro pursuit as well.

However given the handwave of ho it works, this is not really any different than spreading a mundane disease with slow incubation.  Your best bet for spreading is direct human injection and using multiple sites around the world, preferably remote places with minimal healthcare, so it can build up a reserve population to feed outbreaks. More sites reduce the chance of the population being wiped out by a panicking populace or government. Your initial outbreak will take a little longer but it is will be a lot harder to stamp out.

Comment: Or you could go straight for the places that would try to stop the problem. The incubation period is long, but the virus is extremely obvious. I would instead target government agencies that prevent diseases and the military because they would step in to such a situation very early on.

Comment: @JohnLocke thats a bad idea you are basically alerting the worst possible people at a time when they could actually stop you. It like having a plan to overthrow the government that starts with steal a nuclear weapon with five guys in a van.

Comment: But if you infect them first, they can't stop you. It's like Ebola. If it is contained in LDCs, it becomes a high profile disease, so when it gets to more developed countries, those countries are ready to treat it. Imagine if instead a bunch of high up government people from a several MDCs were the first to be infected. Then the government would be unable to organize a response, and the population would be infected. LDCs would not be able to organize a response. With the WHO essentially wiped out, it would spread throughout those countries.

Comment: This does however require you to subdue high profile government officials to inject them without them reporting it, And CDC workers are constantly checked for infection, so chances are the infection will be detected long before transformation, remember how long this infection takes. At which point they will be quarantined which stops your spread cold. more importantly you are giving the CDC access to the virus right from the beginning which drastically lowers the chance of spreading it even if someone escapes.

Comment: The higher-ups will not be checked because they don't work with diseases. If they are infected first, there will be no reason to suspect any diseases. You can also give it to them discreetly- via water or an aerolosolized mist

Answer (score 2):

If you're able to mass-produce this serum (you say you can), presumably cheaply, and if even a low dosage (your stated half a teaspoon) is enough, you have a lot of options. Also, you state that there's a dormant period here: it's a week before any symptoms appear, and the symptoms of Week 2 and Week 3 are vague enough that they won't be seen as a real illness. Vegetarians suddenly starting to eat meat would be a complication, but they won't suspect that they're turning into werewolves; ordinary people would laugh their heads off at that suggestion.

A million dollars is a useful budget, but ill-suited for going the way of an entrepreneur if you're looking at a global scale: you wouldn't be able to spread it very quickly, so you wouldn't get far before people noticed all the disappearances and mutated people, linked them to whatever product (food or drink, probably) you were selling, and acted against you. So that route is out.

If, however, you can **hijack an existing global distribution network** instead of having to build your own, you're golden. Bribery or subterfuge might allow you to get into some major fast food company's supply chain or factories or so on, and from there you have lots of potential. As an example, imagine if you managed to get your serum into, say, the McDonald's Big Mac sauce. Suddenly, you're in a position to infect anybody who eats at any McDonald's supplied by whichever facility you infiltrated, which is going to be a lot of people. The sheer scope of that also makes discovery unlikely; good luck trying to connect Big Macs to a wild and crazy werewolf-creating disease when so many people eat at McDonald's.

You could also go for **directly administering the serum**, passing it off as a vaccine or other medical treatment. This is a little iffy, since medical procedures are (I would hope, at least) designed to guard against the risk of contamination, but no system is impossible to break into. John is on a good track in this regard: you'd probably have good success if you offered your serum (with suitable falsified proofs claiming it to be something else, or a way to hide the serum within a legitimate injection) for some humanitarian program to provide medical care in the Third World. Pick a place with minimal monitoring, and you'll get a nice base population of werewolves at little risk. Pick a few more places to avoid placing all your eggs in one basket, and chances are you'll eventually infect a significant chunk of the world's population.

One more approach is dependent on your serum's properties. You have a dormant period of about three weeks before significant (alarming, obviously ill, etc.) symptoms develop, and you mention that it can be spread through bodily fluids including saliva; at that point, it probably spreads through blood and semen as well. If victims are actively contagious for most of that dormant period (if the virus is able to spread from newly infected victims early on, not just when they're running off into the wild), you're in an excellent position; your virus might not induce coughing or sneezing like the flu does, but people still do it occasionally regardless, so you'd get some improved spreading from that.

It's a rather nasty thing to do, but you could try to **infect prostitutes**, who in the course of their activities will end up turning lots and lots of other individuals into carriers before they run off into the wild, and it would not be easy for anyone to trace it all the way back to you when the first victims no longer have the intelligence or memory to really single out anybody. Bonus points if you can modify your serum's symptoms to include a greatly increased sex drive in the early stages (increasing it in later stages is optional, but the effect would likely persist: the implications and consequences of your werewolves having that massive sex drive post-transformation are left as an exercise for the reader), to encourage further transmission. You'd basically be making a new STI, with the bonus that mere kissing would likely be enough for transmission, and with that long dormant period you are giving your carriers plenty of time to spread it around. Amplify the sex drive of victims, and pretty much anybody who uses the services of prostitutes or has sex with those who do will become infected. You'd most likely see an increase in rape if you did that last part, which (while a very nasty outcome) would likewise spread the infection that much farther.

EDIT: One more entirely plausible route, if you can manage mass production on your budget and available means, would be to **get the serum into local water supplies**, preferably in multiple widely spread locations to ensure widespread infection. You'd infect pretty much everybody in those towns, and if you select towns high up on rivers you'll likely also get the bonus of significant infection in cities farther downstream. I can imagine gallons of this stuff being pumped into, say, the Mississippi/the Nile/the Amazon/(insert other huge and important rivers of your choice here) and infecting tens of millions of people. Not everybody will necessarily get a sufficient dosage, but enough will that they will in turn spread the virus to most of the others.

Comment: Increased sex drive in earlier stages would be helpful, just like rabies. rabid people will have increased sex drive. I like the idea that the people are carriers before they morph and that it's able to do this through kissing, so any future answers can use this information.