# Metamorphosis Lycanthropy Part 2

Tags: biology, creature-design, science-fiction, mythical-creatures

If you notice the part two, yeah I had one before this. Please read it before reading this one: [Metamorphosis Lycanthropy](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/126264/metamorphosis-lycanthropy)
Edit: just figured out it was closed. Sigh . . .

Edit 6

You have been releasing the Werewolf Serum 6 upon countries. You believe that roughly 30,000 humans have successfully morphed in Canada and the U.S. We'll go with 50/50 on gender. They have also formed small packs and are reproducing.
But they aren't thriving. They are struggling to survive for the following reasons. Your friends (3) have agreed to help you and are funding your work, so you have roughly a little more than a million. You have easy access to many different countries.

Lack of Experience:
The wolf-people have the instincts to live but not the experience on how to work together, hunt, roam, etc. They have no parents to teach them to hunt.

Adaption: since we'll base this in Canada and the U.S. the were-people won't survive the winter very well. Should you add some additional traits from other animals or move them to a different environment/country?

Competition: other animals are competing with the wolf-people, as I'm calling them. Mainly wolves, of all things, and humans. They have realized that something is up, but no national wide emergency.

**What are the best ways to combat these problems and keep spreading the WS6?**

Basic anatomy: They have a short tail, heightened senses, a short snout, sharp teeth, fur, claws with a thumb, increased strength, endurance and wolf-like instincts. They have decreased intelligence.

Remember, you need half a teaspoon for it to effect a person. It is easily mass-produced and your goal is to spread it to as many people as possible and turn humanity into beasts quickly.

Comment: 100,000 people converted would definitely make a national wide emergency, unless they are getting locked up to avoid mass panic.

Comment: I'll point out that your were-people are described as growing considerable hair in the linked question. Wolves do just fine in the winter: they can starve, sure, but it's not generally the cold that kills them. Assuming that your were-people grow wolf-like fur (a fairly reasonable guess), cold is actually not going to be a significant problem. Your real problem is, as you mentioned, lack of wilderness experience: even if the transformation comes with the development of suitable instincts, the lack of parents to walk them through their early years is going to result in a high casualty rate.

Comment: You really should include the final anatomy of your creatures in this question, not a link, it is what the whole question hinges on.

Comment: Even humans without the were- augmentation are quite capable of doing quite well in Canadian winters. I remember doing boy scouts camps at -40 degrees in Banff National park. While boy scouts are expected to be skilled, they aren't super human, theyre still just a bunch of city kids.

Comment: I wonder if this is going to be an [on hold] saga.

Comment: John i agree to that statement. a wolf may have instincts but they still need other wolves to raise them.

Answer (score 1):

All of your questions falls down on **ONE** question, How potent is your virus?

Teaching survival to werewolves? Might as well bring them back to being humans, let them study college through a crash course on "Were wolves for DUMMIES" then give them the virus.

The reason why we have huskies rather than wolves is simple, **INSTINCT**.

Wolves are hunters, **killing** hunters, trying to domesticate a wolf is light slithing your neck with a dull blade, after a long time, you'll eventually die, because the blade will eventually cut of your neck. Same goes while trying to domesticate a wolf. Sure, you can keep him while he is still young, have him eat dog food and dont let him smell or taste blood. BUT his blood, his instict will eventually kick in, and the hunger for warm meat will be insatiable.

Competition? There's no competition in the wild, there's just the Circle of life. The strong eats the weak, the smart outsmarts the mindless, the fast outruns the slow, everything is up for grabs, if your were wolves are weak, then maybe dogs might feast on them. But if they cannot even kill a lion, then they are just part of the food chain.

**LACK OF EXPERIENCE**, funny... Insticts should kick in heavily in this scenario. A lone tiger even as a child WILL hunt prey, preferrably something smaller, to suffice his diet. And these tigers are the most lethal when they grow up. Because they are the ones who experienced hunger, and caught their prey through knowledge gained from experience, weather through ambush or sheer power. Now for your were wolves, IF they die within the first years then, If I was one of your investors, I have feed you to the wolves, watch you die painfully so that at the end of the day, I could say to my self it was worth it.

You really have to be one hell of a mad scientist, if you dont, then you will eventually become meat for your investors' dogs.